# Can't read two bytes through Serial.read - Arduino

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, serial-communication

I'm sending via Bluetooth with an Android App two bytes like this:

```
private void _sendCommand(byte command, byte arg)
{
    if (CONNECTED)
    {
        try
        {
            os.write(new byte[]{command, arg});
            os.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error sending command: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code I'm using to receive them with Arduino:

```
byte _instruction;
byte _arg;

void loop() 
{    
  while(Serial.available() < 2)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  }

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  _instruction = Serial.read();
  _arg = Serial.read();
  Serial.flush();

  switch (_instruction) 
  {

     ...

  }
}
```

I don't have any problems sending just one byte (modifying the code to receive just one), but I can't do the same with two bytes. It's always stuck in the `while`. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: you can try posting question here http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ for arduino questions

Comment: There is no while loop on sending side. So where are you talkung about?

Comment: `os.write(new byte[]{command, arg});`. Why so complicated? Why not `os.write(command); os.write(arg);` ?

Comment: @greenapps The while is in the receiving end. I tried with two writes as well and still the same happens.

Comment: Yes i had seen that while of incourse. But that while does not tell you that you cannot send as you said. But that you cannot receive.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry, I don't get it :S That while tells me that I need at least two bytes, which I always send, to continue.

Comment: The only thing that is sure is that you cannot receive two bytes. The rest is speculation. I think it would be good you posted the code to send and receive one byte too. As you said that that worked. Post it in separate code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem with help of ST2000. There was a problem of syncronization between sender and receiver. This is the code working properly:

```
void loop() 
{    
  // Wait until instruction byte has been received.
  while (!Serial.available());
  // Instruction should be read. MSB is set to 1
  _instruction = (short) Serial.read();

  if (_instruction & 0x80)
  {
    // Wait until arg byte has been received.
    while (!Serial.available());
    // Read the argument.
    _arg = (short) Serial.read();

    switch (_instruction) 
    {
      ...
    }
  }

  Serial.flush();
}
```